# Tailwind modifier syntax for multiple condidtions

Tags: tailwind-css

If I want a an HTML link to be styled when it has a class name of "active" *OR* in the hover state, how do I do it with Tailwind CSS?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work when trying to set the font to semibold:

`<a href="#" class="active [&.active]:hover:font-semibold"`

(The `active` class is set by the web framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the variants into two separate classes:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Roboto', ...tailwind.defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      }
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="#" class="active [&.active]:font-semibold hover:font-semibold">
  Foo
</a>
<a href="#" class="[&.active]:font-semibold hover:font-semibold">
  Bar
</a>
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to stick to only one Tailwind class, you could use [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) or [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) in an [arbitrary variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants):

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Roboto', ...tailwind.defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      }
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="#" class="active [&:is(.active,:hover)]:font-semibold">
  Foo
</a>
<a href="#" class="[&:is(.active,:hover)]:font-semibold">
  Bar
</a>

<a href="#" class="active [&:where(.active,:hover)]:font-semibold">
  Foo
</a>
<a href="#" class="[&:where(.active,:hover)]:font-semibold">
  Bar
</a>
```